MQL5 How can open just a one position per day
I mean that if the expert opens a position at any time during the day, it should not open any more positions on that day after that.
I'm trying to check that with this method and put it before opening a new position, but it's not working.
bool IsOneDayPassedSinceLastDeal(string symbol)
{
    int totalDeals = HistoryDealsTotal();
  
    if (totalDeals == 0)
        return true;

    for (int i = totalDeals - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ulong dealTicket = HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
        string dealSymbol = HistoryDealGetString(dealTicket, DEAL_SYMBOL);

        if (dealSymbol == symbol)
        {
            datetime openTime = HistoryDealGetInteger(dealTicket, DEAL_TIME);
            datetime currentTime = TimeCurrent();
            int timeDifference = currentTime - openTime;
            int secondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
            if (timeDifference < secondsInDay)
                return false;
        }
    }

    // If no deal was found for the symbol within the last day, return true
    return true;
}


solution for that Edit the method for this
bool IsOneDayPassedSinceLastDeal()
{
    MqlDateTime currentDate;
    TimeCurrent(currentDate);

    int currentDay = currentDate.day;
  
    int lastDay = _lastPositionTime.day;
     
    if (currentDay == lastDay ) {
        return false; 
    } else {
        return true; 
    }
}

Define MqlDateTime _lastPositionTime; as a public variable
